# Initial State of Array data is undefined within Reducer

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux, redux-persist

I would like to save object data inside my array state.
But when I try to call an action in reducer, the INITIAL_STATE.highlightedVerse always resulted as **undefined** when I tried to console.log() it. It should be an empty array, not undefined.

These are the dependencies that I used in package.json
Expo v32.0.0, 
React v16.5.0, 
Redux v4.0.1, 
React Redux v5.1.1, 
Redux Persist v.5.10.0

These are the code that I wrote:

```
import {
  ADD_BIBLE_VERSE_HIGHLIGHT,
  REMOVE_BIBLE_VERSE_HIGHLIGHT,
} from 'ndc-ministry/redux/actions/types'

const INITIAL_STATE = {
  highlightedVerse: [],
}

const reducer = (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {

  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_BIBLE_VERSE_HIGHLIGHT:
      const currentHighlightedVerse = state.highlightedVerse
      if(currentHighlightedVerse.length > 0){
        currentHighlightedVerse.forEach(obj => {
          if(action.payload.bookIndex == obj.bookIndex 
            && action.payload.chapterIndex == obj.chapterIndex 
            && action.payload.verseIndex == obj.verseIndex
          ) {
            return {...state}
          }
        })
      }

      return {
        ...state,
        highlightedVerse: [...state.highlightedVerse, action.payload]
      }


    case REMOVE_BIBLE_VERSE_HIGHLIGHT:
      const deletedHighlightVerse = state.highlightedVerse.filter(obj => JSON.stringify(action.payload) != JSON.stringify(obj))
      return {
        ...state,
        highlightedVerse: deletedHighlightVerse
      }

    default:
      return state

  }
}

export default reducer
```

In development mode, it works just fine. But when I updated it to production APK/IPA, it always returns undefined and I have no idea how. I already tried to search for two days but still could not understand why.

Thank you for reading this issue and I hope someone could help me on this :)

Comment: You need to show how you connect your component, your action dispatchers and how is your root reducer setup.

Comment: Sounds like something that it is not easy to solve. How about initializing it explicitly when you start the app?

Comment: can you show us the code where you create the Store?

Answer (score 2):

I think you have an issue in `mapStateToProps` function. If you change it to have the state object (*BibleReducer*) without destructuring assignment in the function's parameter list then you will have the value in *hightlightedVerse* property as needed.

You can check the value by debugging or doing `console.log(BibleReducer)` to test where and how your variable's value show up in the code.

Original one - from your code with destructuring the value is undefined:

```
function mapStateToProps({BibleReducer}) {
  console.log(BibleReducer);

  return {
    highlightedVerse: BibleReducer.highlightedVerse,
  }
}
```

I guess the working one - you should have the state object:

```
function mapStateToProps(BibleReducer) {
  console.log(BibleReducer);

  return {
    highlightedVerse: BibleReducer.highlightedVerse,
  }
}
```

Please read further about destructuring assignment [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).

> The destructuring assignment syntax is a JavaScript expression that makes it possible to unpack values from arrays, or properties from objects, into distinct variables.

With destructuring you are referencing to `state.BibleReducer.highlightedVerse` property and I think that is why the value is showed as undefined.

Let me know if this works or not, we can think further if needed.

**UPDATE**:
If you would like to use still destructuring assigment then you can go for the following solution to use only `highlightedVerse` array value:

```
function mapStateToProps({highlightedVerse}) {
   console.log(highlightedVerse);

   return {
      highlightedVerse: highlightedVerse,
   }
}
```

Thanks @Clarity for the idea!

Comment: It can be just `const mapStateToProps = (state) => ( {
    highlightedVerse: state.highlightedVerse,
})`

Comment: I don't think that's the problem, because I used combinedReducer, and it works normally with other files. I already console.log everything up to the reducer. I saw the action.payload works fine. But the reducer prints undefined when I console.log(state.highlightedVerse)

Comment: What value you have when you do a logging like console.log(state); only?

Comment: @norbitrial it prints

Object {
"highlightedVerse": Array [],
"notedVerse": Array [],
"selectedBookIndex": 0,
"selectedChapterIndex": 0,
"selectedVerseIndex": 0,
}

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Clarity @Yossi @Domino987

Here is my store/index.js

```
import { AsyncStorage } from 'react-native'
import storage from 'redux-persist/lib/storage'
import { createStore } from 'redux'
import { persistStore, persistReducer } from 'redux-persist'
import reducers from 'ndc-ministry/redux/reducers'

const persistConfig = {
  key: 'root',
  storage: AsyncStorage
}

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, reducers)

export const store = createStore(
  persistedReducer,
)

export const persistor = persistStore(store)
```

The weird thing is, every state in my redux is stored & persisted WELL, except when the state is an array. This is how I dispatch my action in the React component

```
 import { addBibleVerseHighlight } from 'project-name/redux/actions'
    class BibleScreen extends Component {

addHighlight = () => {
    this.state.selectedVersesIndex.map((value) => {
      const verseData = {
        bookIndex: this.props.selectedBookIndex,
        chapterIndex: this.props.selectedChapterIndex,
        verseIndex: value,
      }

        this.props.addBibleVerseHighlight(verseData)

    })
  }

    render() { ... }
    }


    function mapStateToProps({BibleReducer}) {
      return {
        highlightedVerse: BibleReducer.highlightedVerse,
      }
    }

    const mapDispatchToProps = {
      addBibleVerseHighlight,
      removeBibleVerseHighlight,
    }

    export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(BibleScreen)
```

Comment: You'd move this code to your question, by editing it.

Answer (score 0):

I would say simplify your reducer and remove the `highlightedVerse` field.
And then treat your state like the Array it is instead of an Array of an Object.

So change from `{}` to `[]` where applicable.

For example (and without testing):

```
import {
  ADD_BIBLE_VERSE_HIGHLIGHT,
  REMOVE_BIBLE_VERSE_HIGHLIGHT,
} from 'ndc-ministry/redux/actions/types'

const INITIAL_STATE = [];

const reducer = (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {

  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_BIBLE_VERSE_HIGHLIGHT:
      const currentHighlightedVerse = [...state];

      if(currentHighlightedVerse.length > 0){
        currentHighlightedVerse.forEach(obj => {
          if(action.payload.bookIndex == obj.bookIndex 
            && action.payload.chapterIndex == obj.chapterIndex 
            && action.payload.verseIndex == obj.verseIndex
          ) {
            return state;
          }
        })
      }

      return [...state, action.payload];


    case REMOVE_BIBLE_VERSE_HIGHLIGHT:
      const deletedHighlightVerse = state.filter(obj => JSON.stringify(action.payload) != JSON.stringify(obj))

      return deletedHighlightVerse;

    default:
      return state

  }
}

export default reducer
```

This way in your initialState for your store... your `highlightedVerse` field can be an empty array and you can set this reducer as the reducer for that field.

Good luck.

Comment: Hello! Thank for answering this. Actually in my real case, the INITIAL_STATE has many fields. Not just one. I just simplify my code above because it is too much to show everything. And I realized the problem is in the INITIAL_STATE where the default value is array. Others INITIAL_STATE possess no problem